# How to create tooltip with vue.js?

Tags: vue.js, tooltip

I am creating simple application using Vue2, In my application i need tooltip with interactive buttons, this tooltip should only appear when text in textarea is selected, I want to find library like
https://www.cssscript.com/tooltip-text-selection-texttip/, but for Vue2, After a very long search I could not find anything like this, I also tried to use `v-tooltip` but it But I could not find that kind of tooltip, any Offer?

Comment: Why don't you use the one from the link?

Comment: It throws an webpack error, I can't install it via Npm

Comment: Then grab the code from their source from github.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just use plain html and css: Check out this link:
[w3schools css tooltip](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_tooltip.asp)

and conditionally show by using v-if as shown examples in the Vue docs
[v-if Vue Docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html)

Answer (score 1):

Exist bootstrap-vue.

[section for tooltips](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/tooltip#tooltips)

And you can add a v-if to the component when selecting the text show tooltip with a true property.

Answer (score 0):

Since there's no code I don't know exactly what is the problem but, it could matter of timing.
What about try to init tooltip after view load complete?